# SCP wrapper to download files easily

Tags: unix, ssh

I would like to know if there exists some wrapper to scp that can easily let me download files from a remote system. I would just like to point to my SSH server and then remote files should be easily navigable. Ideally it should put downloads in some sort of background so one can keep looking for other files as well. File have very long names, can contain lots of extra chars like spaces etc. I don't want to download from scratch if there was a partial copy already. Preferably it should also match md5 sum of the files.

I can make one if none exists, but not too interested in making one if a working solution already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your environment, there are different tools.  Most "ftp" applications today can do "sftp" which is a close-cousin to scp... and most servers that support scp will also support sftp with no configuration changes.  If you're only able to use native scp... your options are less, but at the very least in Windows, you can use [winscp](http://winscp.net).

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla http://filezilla-project.org/
and many other ftp/sftp clients support your requirements